# Use of the ceiling fan's red wire

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Can I use the unused red wire in the wiring from my ceiling fan to power a light in my attic space? Leaving the switch wiring the same (meaning i could turn the attic light off and on via the fan switch?)

Comment: The wire doesn't care what it powers. Do you have a more specific question? A description of the circuit would also be useful.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The red wire you speak of is presumably the switched hot from a wall switch that currently powers the fan when the wall switch is closed. Is this red wire in a 14-3 + gnd NM cable? Or is this wires in conduit? So you are asking if a separate light can be put in parallel with the fan and controlled by the same wall switch as the fan?

Comment: Is the attic light close to the fan? Or would you need to extend the unused red wire in some way?